# smartctl not working on Seagate Firecuda NVMe drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-disk, smartctl

I have a Seagate Firecuda drive that appears to be working, but I cannot get smartctl information on it... is it that this particular drive does not support smartctl or something else?

Using lshw I see the device:

```
                 *-storage
                      description: Non-Volatile memory controller
                      product: Seagate Technology PLC
                      vendor: Seagate Technology PLC
                      physical id: 0
                      bus info: pci@0000:43:00.0
                      version: 01
                      width: 64 bits
                      clock: 33MHz
                      capabilities: storage pciexpress msix msi pm nvm_express bus_master cap_list
                      configuration: driver=nvme latency=0
                      resources: irq:51 memory:b7f00000-b7f03fff
```

It is mounted and working:

```
$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1     259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   931G  0 part /
```

But smartctl gives an error:

```
$ sudo smartctl -A /dev/nvme0n1
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-112-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
Read NVMe SMART/Health Information failed: NVMe Status 0x2002
```

```
$ sudo smartctl -A /dev/nvme0n1p1
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-112-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
Read NVMe SMART/Health Information failed: NVMe Status 0x2002
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version of smartmontools is very old (four years old!). Please try installing smartmontools 7.1 or even an SVN snapshot because it usually contains a lot of fixes and workarounds. In particular, NVMe support wasn’t great before version 7.0; starting with 7.0, `smartctl` defaults to the broadcast SID which should be used for SMART status queries on NVMe devices.